# Laravel - paypal keep maximum 30 second exceed

Tags: paypal, laravel-5.5, timeoutexception

Paypal in laravel keep returning maximum 30 seconds timeout, sometime it can proceed smoothly but when cart product increase, it will keep return this error, and sometime the error is when create payment, sometime is execute payment, extremely not stable, how can i solve this? i have tried extend the timeout setting to 300, but it still return me a timeout error.

here is my create payment code:

```
$item_array = [];
      $shipping = $request->shipping;
      $tax = $request->tax;
      $tax_amount = 0;
      $subtotal = $total = 0;
      $currency = "MYR";
      $payer = new Payer();
      $payer->setPaymentMethod("paypal");
      $credential = new OAuthTokenCredential(env('PAYPAL_SANDBOX_CLIENT_ID'), env('PAYPAL_SANDBOX_SECRET'));
      $apiContext = new ApiContext($credential, null);
      $order = Order::findOrFail($id);
      // change order product status
      foreach ($order->orderProduct as $order_product_key => $order_product) {
        // get variant
        $variant_title_array = array();
        if (count($order_product->variantValue) > 0) {
          foreach ($order_product->variantValue->variantOption as $variant_option) {
            array_push($variant_title_array, $variant_option->name);
          }
        }

        $variant= "";
        if (count($variant_title_array) > 0) {
          $variant = " ( ".implode(', ', $variant_title_array)." )";
        }

        // calculate product price and promotion price
        $product_price = $compare_price = "";
        $product_promotion = get_cart_product_promotion ($order_product, $order);

        $product_price = get_product_price_in_cart ($order_product);

        // if promotion exits
        if (count($product_promotion) != 0) {
          $compare_price = get_product_price_in_cart ($order_product);

          $product_price = calculate_product_price_after_promotion ($compare_price, $product_promotion);
        }

        $item = new Item();
        $item->setName($order_product->product->title . $variant)
            ->setCurrency($currency)
            ->setQuantity($order_product->quantity)
            ->setSku(get_product_sku_in_cart ($order_product)) // Similar to `item_number` in Classic API
            ->setPrice((float) str_replace('RM ','', $product_price));
        $item_array[$order_product_key] = $item;
        $subtotal += (float) str_replace('RM ','', $product_price) * $order_product->quantity;
      }

      // calculate tax
      $tax_amount = ($subtotal * $tax) / 100;


      $itemList = new ItemList();
      $itemList->setItems($item_array);

      $shipping_address = new ShippingAddress();

      $shipping_address->setCity('City')
        ->setCountryCode('AR')
        ->setPostalCode('200')
        ->setLine1('Adress Line1')
        ->setState('State')
        ->setRecipientName('Recipient Name');

      $details = new Details();
      $details->setShipping($shipping)
          ->setTax($tax_amount)
          ->setSubtotal($subtotal);

      $total = $subtotal + $shipping + $tax_amount;
      $amount = new Amount();
      $amount->setCurrency($currency)
          ->setTotal($total)
          ->setDetails($details);

      $transaction = new Transaction();
      $transaction->setAmount($amount)
          ->setItemList($itemList)
          ->setDescription("Payment description")
          ->setInvoiceNumber(uniqid());

      $baseUrl = url('/');
      $redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
      $redirectUrls->setReturnUrl("$baseUrl/ExecutePayment.php?success=true")
          ->setCancelUrl("$baseUrl/ExecutePayment.php?success=false");

      $payment = new Payment();
      $payment->setIntent("sale")
          ->setPayer($payer)
          ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)
          ->setTransactions(array($transaction));

      $request = clone $payment;

      try {
          $payment->create($apiContext);
      } catch (PayPalConnectionException $ex) {
          echo $ex->getCode(); // Prints the Error Code
          echo $ex->getData(); // Prints the detailed error message
          die($ex);
      } catch (Exception $ex) {
          die($ex);
      }

      $approvalUrl = $payment->getApprovalLink();

      $response = array(
        'paymentID' => $payment->id
      );

      return json_encode($response);
```

here is my execute payment code:

```
$shipping = $request->shipping;
      $tax = $request->tax;
      $tax_amount = 0;
      $subtotal = $total = 0;
      $currency = "MYR";

      $credential = new OAuthTokenCredential(env('PAYPAL_SANDBOX_CLIENT_ID'), env('PAYPAL_SANDBOX_SECRET'));
      $apiContext = new ApiContext($credential, null);
      $paymentId = $request->paymentID;
      $payment = Payment::get($paymentId, $apiContext);

      $transaction = new Transaction();
      $amount = new Amount();
      $details = new Details();

      $order = Order::findOrFail($id);

      // store order address
      $order_address = OrderAddress::firstOrCreate(
        [
          'order_id' => $order->id
        ],
        [
          'name' => $request->shipping_name ,
          'phone' => $request->shipping_phone ,
          'address1' => $request->shipping_address1 ,
          'address2' => $request->shipping_address2 ,
          'postcode' => $request->shipping_postcode ,
          'state' => $request->shipping_state ,
          'country' => $request->shipping_country ,
          'city' => $request->shipping_city ,
          'order_id' => $order->id
        ]
      );

      // update address if exist
      $order_address->update([
        'name' => $request->shipping_name ,
        'phone' => $request->shipping_phone ,
        'address1' => $request->shipping_address1 ,
        'address2' => $request->shipping_address2 ,
        'postcode' => $request->shipping_postcode ,
        'state' => $request->shipping_state ,
        'country' => $request->shipping_country ,
        'order_id' => $order->id
      ]);

      // change order product status
      foreach ($order->orderProduct as $order_product) {

        // calculate product price and promotion price
        $product_price = $compare_price = "";
        $product_promotion = get_cart_product_promotion ($order_product, $order);

        $product_price = get_product_price_in_cart ($order_product);

        // if promotion exits
        if (count($product_promotion) != 0) {
          $compare_price = get_product_price_in_cart ($order_product);

          $product_price = calculate_product_price_after_promotion ($compare_price, $product_promotion);
        }

        $product_price = (float) str_replace("RM ","",$product_price);

        // add promotion to order product if promotion exist
        if ($compare_price != "") {
          $order_product->order_promotion_id = $order->orderPromotion->promotion_id;
        }

        $order_product->price = $product_price;
        $order_product->status = 2;

        $subtotal += $product_price * $order_product->quantity;

        $order_product->save();
      }

      // calculate tax
      $tax_amount = ($subtotal * $tax) / 100;

      // change cart detail
      $current_date_time = Carbon::now();
      $order->update([
        'subtotal' => $subtotal,
        'status' => 2,
        'submited_on' => $current_date_time,
        'payment_method' => "paypal"
      ]);

      // update shipping fees
      if ($shipping > 0) {
        $order->shipping_fees = $shipping;
      }

      // update tax
      if ($tax > 0) {
        $order->tax = ($subtotal * $tax) / 100;
      }

      $order->save();


      // paypal settings
      $total = $subtotal + $shipping + $tax_amount;

      $details->setShipping($shipping)
          ->setTax($tax_amount)
          ->setSubtotal($subtotal);
      $amount->setCurrency($currency);
      $amount->setTotal($total);
      $amount->setDetails($details);
      $transaction->setAmount($amount);
      // Add the above transaction object inside our Execution object.
      $execution->addTransaction($transaction);

      try {

          $result = $payment->execute($execution, $apiContext);

          try {
              $payment = Payment::get($paymentId, $apiContext);
          } catch (Exception $ex) {

              exit(1);
          }
      } catch (Exception $ex) {

          exit(1);
      }


      echo "success";
```